# Set a UIViewController inside a switch/case statement using Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to load a view based on a button press. I thought I could do something like this below where I defined a generic UIViewController and then set it to a specific UIViewController inside a switch/case statement but it apparently doesn't work this way. What am I doing wrong?

```
@objc func menuButton(sender: UIButton) {
    var view: UIViewController!
    switch sender.tag {
        case 0:
            view = MenuViewController()
            view.menuType = .Account
        case 1:
            view = MenuViewController()
            view.menuType = .Sync
        case 2:
            view = AuthViewController()
            view.menuType = .Auth
        default: break
    }
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: before switch starts, check the value of tag by print(sender.tag).
may be tag not passed correctly .

Comment: The code doesn't even compile. I get "Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'menuType'" so it looks like because I initially defined view as UIViewController, I can't cast it to my MenuViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the compiler should give an error saying:

> Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'menuType'

Here you have a couple of options to solve this:

**Solution 1**

Use casting

```
@objc func menuButton(sender: UIButton) {
    var view: UIViewController!
    switch sender.tag {
        case 0:
            view = MenuViewController()
            (view as? MenuViewController())?.menuType = .Account
        case 1:
            view = MenuViewController()
            (view as? MenuViewController())?.menuType = .Sync
        case 2:
            view = AuthViewController()
            (view as? AuthViewController())?.menuType = .Auth
        default: break
    }
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
}
```

**Solution 2**

Create a protocol `MenuProtocol`

```
protocol MenuProtocol {
    var menuType: MenuType { get set }
}
```

and make the `MenuViewController` and `AuthViewController` implement that protocol. Then you can do the following:

```
@objc func menuButton(sender: UIButton) {
    var view: (UIViewController & MenuProtocol)!
    switch sender.tag {
        case 0:
            view = MenuViewController()
            view.menuType = .Account
        case 1:
            view = MenuViewController()
            view.menuType = .Sync
        case 2:
            view = AuthViewController()
            view.menuType = .Auth
        default: break
    }
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Wow, I tried for an hour to come up with just one solution and you gave 2 within a minute! Thanks

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)